# log request body using scala http filter

Tags: java, scala, filter, playframework

i am using this filter to save log about request and response time:

```
import play.api.Logger
import play.api.mvc._
import scala.concurrent.Future
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext

object LoggingFilter extends Filter {
  def apply(nextFilter: (RequestHeader) => Future[SimpleResult])
           (requestHeader: RequestHeader): Future[SimpleResult] = {
    val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis
    nextFilter(requestHeader).map { result =>
      val endTime = System.currentTimeMillis
      val requestTime = endTime - startTime
      Logger.info(s"${requestHeader.method} ${requestHeader.uri} " +
        s"took ${requestTime}ms and returned ${result.header.status}")
      result.withHeaders("Request-Time" -> requestTime.toString)
    }
  }
}
```

however i need to save the request body in the log. i know that this can be done using Scala action composition but i cant figure out how to get this done.
any help??

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access to the request body, you need to override the method `apply(EssentialAction)` of an `EssentialFilter` object.

For reference :

- [Play documentation, "More powerful filters" paragraph](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaHttpFilters)
- [Understanding the Play Filter API, by James Roper](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/02/understanding-the-play-filter-api.html)

Comment: thanks, i already read that the issue is i need some help in implementing that as i build my whole project using java and i know nothing about scala.